# swiftでSWTableViewCellを使用したいのですが、ボタンは表示されてもセル自体が左右に動いてくれません。

Tags: swift, ios, tableview

初めて質問させていただきます。
タイトルにある通り、swiftの環境でSWTableViewCellを使用したいのですが、スワイプしてもセルが左右に動きません。

SWTableViewCell
https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell

上記のサンプルのように動かすにはどこをどのように設定すればよいのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: SWTableViewCell についてはよく知りませんが、同様の操作は iOS 8 から UITableViewRowAction, iOS 11 から UISwipeActionsConfiguration としてUIKitのクラスとして提供されています。前者は右から左のスワイプのみですが、こちらを使った方が早いかもしれませんよ。

Comment: ありがとうございます。UIKitのものも検討したのですが、スワイプ 時の動きをLINEのようにしたいと思い、LINEもSWtableViewCellを使っていたため試してみようと思いました。 先程、試行錯誤の結果、原因はセルの中身のビューに対してオートレイアウトを使用していたからだと判明しました。オートレイアウトをやめたら動きました！ありがとうございました。